# Adding your own RPM to kickstart file in SL

Tags: kickstart

I have a kickstart file I am working on for my servers:

```
repo --name="Scientific Linux"  --baseurl=http://ftp1.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.5/i386/os/ --cost=100

%packages
@client-mgmt-tools
@core --nodefaults
@misc-sl
vim
tree
lzop
man-pages
openssh-clients
epel-release
zip
unzip
%end
```

I am looking to add an RPM I built: `supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm`

Can anyone tell me what the correct convention would be to adding this to my kickstart file so that the RPM installs? Please note, I have already added the kickstart file and my RPM to my work's repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a repo for the RPM first.

```
$ mkdir supportScripts
$ cp supportScripts-0.1-1.noarch.rpm supportScripts
$ createrepo supportScripts
```

You will then have to either add the repo to your iso or point kickstart at that repository location.

If all that has already been done then all you need to do is add the name of the RPM to the list of packages to install.

Comment: I already have a repository location and my RPM has been added there. Is there a way to have the kickstart file point to my repository where the RPM is located? And if I add the RPM to the KS file, what is the correct format for adding it? Would I add it with the list of the other programs (tree, zip, unzip, etc) are?

Comment: So this isn't a remote install. You have some packages on the iso DVD and then you want to point Kickstart at the extra package in your local repository? Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Yes... add it with the list of other programs

Comment: Thanks, I know it is a very simple question. But i couldnt find many sources for this question online :)

Comment: Okay. There are several ways to do this. You can edit the contents of the iso and add your package to the repository on the iso. Then add it to the list. Or you will need to point kickstart at a post install script that creates a repo file and then executes a yum install.